# Disable a Navigation Bar Button upon Application Launch

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have an application that requires to select a client to work with when the application is launched. I am initiating a segue from the app delegate to a modal view that allows the user to make the selection. The view has a left bar button that says "cancel" and dismissed the view. I want this to be disabled when the user first selects a client, but to be enabled all subsequent times the user opens the client select pane.

I have an IBOutlet in the select client view called cancelButton.

In my prepareForSegue method in the view controller that is launching the segue, I have

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"selectClient"]) {
 if (firstSegue) {
    SelectClientViewController *select = (SelectClientViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    select.cancelButton.enabled = NO;
 }
 firstSegue = NO;
}
```

However, the button remains enabled on the first launch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if i got your question, maybe just try `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;` to disable the right button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `prepareForSegue` is called the view hasn't been loaded. If you don't do anything to make it during the method then the view won't be loaded till later. If the view hasn't been loaded then the outlets aren't available (they haven't been loaded yet either). So, the problem is that the button you are trying to disable doesn't exist yet.

Set a flag on the destination controller so it disables the button in `viewDidLoad` or ensure that the view is loaded before you try to set any view properties.